# 3D payment handling in Ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, payment, ionic3

I'm developing a hybrid application in Ionic 3 Framework,
which should handle 3D payments, so that consumers will be redirected to an external
page for filling in a card information (number, CVV/CVV2, etc.).

Can you please someone tell, what's the most preferred way for making redirections to and/or opening external pages in Ionic 3?

Comment: Did it work for you, I'm trying to do the same with ionic 4, what is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [In App Browser](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-browser/) might be what you are looking for.
It opens the external page inside your App and stores Cookies if you need some.
How to use it, is explained good enough on the official Page I linked.